# VB.Net Text File vs Database for storing data?

Tags: c#, vb.net, mongodb

just a quick question that I am sure someone on here can give me a detailed answer about.

Basically, I am using a DataGridView to display records from a database, which in my case is simply a text file which is being parsed.  I feel this is simple, and if I want to select records based on certain parameters, I iterate through the list searching for matches.  However, I wonder if this is ineffective vs using a full blown DB such as Mongo or SQL.

Can I get away with this if my software is relatively simple?  I really prefer to sway from complicating things, when they don't need to be complicated.

By the way, I am expecting to have a DB (sometimes) larger than 100k entries, so take that into consideration.

Comment: Are you planning on doing this for testing the application or deploying the application into production?

Comment: Deploying, but only for myself.  It is private software.

Comment: Well you would not know how your software would evolve overtime, What if the number of records grow to hundreds of thousands? and what if you need to manage relation data?. so plan ahead. go with an RDBMS.

Comment: Yes, I imagine they could exceed 100k Ahsan, so how much will this factor into performance?  Reading a 100k line text file vs reading a 100k record Mongo or SQL DB

Comment: Why not implement both?  This would be a great opportunity to learn about abstracting implementations behind interfaces.  Create a data access layer interface and three separate implementations.  One for a text file, one for SQL, one for Mongo.  Compare and contrast your experiences with them.

Comment: Look into SQLite. It will be faster than parsing *and converting* 100k records from a text file.  Personally I think MySQL cant be beat for such things, but SQLite would suffice.

Comment: Going down a NoSql or Standard Sql path depends on the needs of your software, with the limited info you have given its difficult to tell you which path to take. Will there be only one table for the life of your application?

Comment: @David True, I love to learn of course, but at the moment I really just want to finish up this project I'm working on, as I've already spent a good 30 hours on it.  I suppose it is worth doing both, just for the sake of it.  I guess you realized I am just trying to avoid doing things the harder, but more robust way :P

Comment: @Ahsan Yes, one table.  Pretty simple DB.

Comment: Do you plan on updating the records in the file?

Comment: @Plutonix Thanks for the suggestion, gonna look into it.

Comment: @Sometowngeek Yes.

Comment: @DavidStampher: In that case SQL would probably be the easiest and most straightforward implementation.  At the very least it's the most common and would have the most tooling and resources available.

Comment: @David I have heard that MongoDB is about 100x (or more?) faster than SQL, seems significant.  But I haven't personally tested that.  The source of that info seemed like they had.

But SQL has been around longer and used by more people.  So I'm struggling here...here is just 1 link to support this, haven't really looked around at the other google results.  https://blog.michaelckennedy.net/2010/04/29/mongodb-vs-sql-server-2008-performance-showdown/

Comment: SQLite is simple, no server app/service, just a file and of course the DB Provider from NuGet. Both are easy to install.  (and "SQL" is a db query language not a DB)

Comment: @DavidStampher: Any statistic like that is going to be meaningless unless the implementation specifically applies to what you're doing.  Tool A may be "faster" than Tool B when used for things Tool A was designed to do.  Hammers are 10X better at hammering nails than screwdrivers are, but they're pretty useless at driving screws.

Comment: Ok guys.  So it seems the consensus is, if I'm going to have more than 100k records and will be updating it often, don't use a text file?  I guess it is just being lazy...lol  I'm just curious what the performance difference really would be.  I suppose I could just test that myself...

Comment: @DavidStampher, you will find yourself spending more time developing a program to read and update a text file than a SQL table. Better do what they say ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@DavidStampher

Even though you may be using just one table or file, I would strongly suggest using a database system for this. Database engines are optimized for speed so it's not so frustrating or time-consuming when performing via query versus trying to update a single text file.

I'm only suggesting MySQL as an option because it's the one I am most familiar with. Other users may have different or better suggestions.

You can easily download and install one from [MySQL installer](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/installer/). The setup is relatively simple and should take less than 10 minutes. You could create a new schema, add a table, then query up to do what you need.

I would suggest creating a new user other than root, just in case someone manages to hack into your account.

If you would like the easiest way to manage the database rather than going through the old fashioned phpMyAdmin, download [MySQL Workbench](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/workbench/). It's pretty cool and relatively easy to use.

Let me know if you have questions. :-)

Comment: Thanks to you and everyone else that replied.  That was pretty fast!  :)

Comment: If you already have data in a separate text file like a TSV or CSV, then it should be relatively easy to import it into the table. Assuming, it's organized, of course :-)

Comment: Microsoft Sql Server Express is free too.